# CSS: Any way to create top to bottom arrow?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a CSS-related question here. I want to create a horizontal arrow, like this on screen shot (actually it was added in paint).

As a possible solution I thought of using the `transform: skew` property, but I don't think it is possible to skew one element on left&right sides.

Any suggestion about this, please? :)

[image]

Comment: Why not use a graphic?

Comment: Good idea, though the task is to create the same via pure CSS. You could use a graphics even for triangles, can't you? :)

Comment: @Joshua i think in 2015, the question is 'why use a graphic?' css is perfectly capable of this and is the right place to put it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible using "a single div" by taking advantage of the `:before` and `:after` selector.

```css
.arrow {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 40px;
}
.arrow:before {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(50% - 2px);
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-right-width: 0;
  transform: skewY(10deg);
}
.arrow:after {
  content: '';
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(50% - 2px);
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-left-width: 0;
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

Comment: Nicely done. I got as far as `skew` (as opposed to `rotate`) then fell flat. Great answer.

Comment: if the arrow has any function beyond decoration then more mark-up would be required for accessibility reasons